# Potential issue due to BigQuery caching

Tags: google-bigquery

BQ caches by default, the output of every query we execute, in a temporary table. We do not have visibility to the table name and the cache duration(could be upto 24 hrs as per documentation).

Now let’s say a report ABC executes a query against a sales table at 5 pm. At 5 am next day, the sales table gets updated. The report ABC run at 8am could still come from cache created at 5pm.

How do I ensure the 8am report returns the updated sales data?

Comment: is this actually happening to you - or this is just hypothetical question?

Comment: it was a hypothetical question. Turns out I just had to read documentation properly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set useQueryCache parameter of job configuration to false

> useQueryCache - boolean
>
> [Optional] Whether to look for the result in the query cache. The
>   query cache is a best-effort cache that will be flushed whenever
>   tables in the query are modified. Moreover, the query cache is only
>   available when a query does not have a destination table specified.
>   The default value is true.

see more in [JobConfigurationQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#JobConfigurationQuery)

Comment: BigQuery uses the last modification time of the referenced tables to decide whether caching is valid, so this is not necessary.

Comment: but will definitelly insure not using cache  - in case if there is some issue with its proper using as OP claims - so will not harm :o)